# Changing pages using socket.io express js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I've seen similar questions, but still couldn't find the solution to my issue. I'm try to create a board game with socket.io but without rooms. In the first page the player enters the name it should be routed to the next page. But that is not happening. Here is my code.
index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
var count = 0;
var users = {};
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render("Welcome");
});
app.get("/wait", function(req, res){
    res.render("Waiting");
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        count++;
        users[msg] = socket.id;
        console.log(users);
        console.log(count);        //count = 1
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
console.log(count); //count = 0
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    if(count === 1)
    {
        res.redirect('/wait');
    }    
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

I want it to go to wait.ejs when count=1. How to solve the count problem?

welcome.ejs:

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Game</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" required />
                <button>Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var socket = io();
            $('form').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#inputUsername').val());
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

As of now I've not added any css. There is no error but app.post() is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure its because you're cancelling the form submission. The chat message gets emmited, count gets updated but the actual form doesn't get posted. You could keep it like this but make an ajax request to the / route (using fetch or axios). Or simply remove e.preventDefault() but that would reload the page.